# Evenly spaced HTML elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get even space between the font awesome icon and the paragraph of text to it's right, which is separated by a divider (in this the case, the `right-border` of the icon).

How can I make the space between the icon and it's border even, the same as the space between icons border and paragraph of text? I'm using flex's `space-between` at the moment, as well as some padding, but the space isn't evenly distributed, and it gets worse as the screen resizes.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#display {
  height: 76%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  width: 95%;
}

.content i {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.text {
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 6%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="container">
  <div id="display">
    <div class="content">
      <i class="fas fa-balance-scale fa-7x"></i>
      <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut scelerisque volutpat libero, at venenatis dolor rutrum vel. Donec fermentum eleifend tortor, at sollicitudin est rutrum nec. Fusce eget vehicula ex. Vestibulum semper gravida nulla, in aliquam ipsum dignissim nec.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
.content i {
  padding-right: 35px;
}
```